# Automating Saving a file from the web with the IE COM object in Powershell

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, com

I'm using IE11's COM object in Powershell to authenticate to a website and pull down a list of orders.  So far, my script is successfully sending the username and password as well as getting to the orders page and I can even "click" on the link that downloads the file I need.  The problem is that instead of saving the file like I need to do the open/saveas dialog comes up and the script bombs.

[image]

I've attempted to have IE11 automatically save the file by [editing the registry and specifying the Excel.CSV type](http://9to5it.com/internet-explorer-disable-do-you-want-to-open-or-save-this-file-prompt/) but this didn't work.  The download link is actually a button that calls a complicated Javascript function and in the end results of the CSV file I need but I've tried to decipher the JS that issues a POST request and use the Navigate() method on the IE COM object to no avail.

I realize this isn't the best way to automate a web process but I couldn't figure out how to work around all the Javascript on the page to use a cmdlet like Invoke-WebRequest.  It's kinda hard to just use HTTP GETs and POSTS when EVERYTHING is Javascript!

Any help is greatly appreciated. Here's a code sample.

```
Function Get-PageElement ($Name,$TagName,$Id) {
    if ($Name) {
        $InternetExplorer.Document.getElementsByName($Name)
    } elseif ($TagName) {
        $InternetExplorer.Document.getElementsByTagName($TagName)
    } elseif ($Id) {
        $InternetExplorer.Document.getElementById($Id)   
    }
}


$script:InternetExplorer = New-Object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$script:InternetExplorer.visible = $true
$InternetExplorer.Navigate($Url)


$DownloadButton = Get-PageElement -Id btnExport
$DownloadButton.Click()
```

Comment: Can you post a code sample of what you are using?

Answer (score 4):

```
#Start IE and navigate to your download file/location
$ie = New-Object -Com internetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate("http://www.your.website.here.com/awesome_stuff/DOC_1.docx")

#------------------------------
#Wait for Download Dialog box to pop up
Sleep 5
while($ie.Busy){Sleep 1} 
#------------------------------

#Hit "S" on the keyboard to hit the "Save" button on the download box
$obj = new-object -com WScript.Shell
$obj.AppActivate('Internet Explorer')
$obj.SendKeys('s')

#Hit "Enter" to save the file
$obj.SendKeys('{Enter}')

#Closes IE Downloads window
$obj.SendKeys('{TAB}')
$obj.SendKeys('{TAB}')
$obj.SendKeys('{TAB}')
$obj.SendKeys('{Enter}')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't parse the javascript and get the url you need you can use wscript to send the key strokes. Note that this is probably a terrible idea and I wouldn't recommend it if there is any way at all to parse the javascript and get the raw url to use a WebClient to download.

```
$wsh = new-object -comobject wscript.shell
$id = (Get-Process iexplore* | Where-Object{$_.MainWindowTitle -match "YOUR.WEB.PAGE.TITLE.HERE"}).id
if($wsh.AppActivate($id)){
    start-sleep -milliseconds 500
    $wsh.SendKeys("{S}")
    #I don't have IE11 stuck on 8 due to corporate policy you may need a second sendkeys here
    #if so insert a 500 millisecond delay
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't so that because this is going to be executed in a scheduled task without a window open. :(