# Downloading files from IE11 using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, internet-explorer-11

I'm currently trying to work on a method of downloading files from a website using PowerShell v2. So far I can navigate to the appropriate page and click the link to download, however, when I do this the download banner appears at the bottom of the page asking me whether I'd like to open or save the file.

Does anyone know how to reference this banner in PowerShell (or even if it's possible), or failing that perhaps a method of turning off the alerts and saving as default?

[Here's an example of a download banner from IE11 that I mention above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhi9a.jpg)

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automating Saving a file from the web with the IE COM object in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401789/automating-saving-a-file-from-the-web-with-the-ie-com-object-in-powershell)

Comment: If not behind a login page (otherwise it's more complicated), you could get the url and use a webclient object. $webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.DownloadFile('url','Filename.ext')